# Backbone + Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I'm trying to use `image_path` to put images on a backbone view like:

```
<%= image_path('logo.png') %>
```

but it doesn't work. I get an error that says:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: image_path is not defined
```

I don't know how to configure `image_path` in order to search in `/assets/images`.

#### login_index.coffee

```
class viaapp.Views.Login extends Backbone.View

template: JST['logins/login_index']

render: (username) ->
@username = username
$(@el).html(@template({user: @username}))
@
```

#### login_index.jst.ejs

```
<img id="profile-img" class="profile-img-card" src="<%= asset_path ('logo.png') %>" />
```

Comment: (1) Is that the real indentation in your CoffeeScript? (2) `image_path` is a Rails view helper, not a (Coffee|Java)Script function that you can use in Backbone.

Comment: Isn't th identation, but the question is: I have backbone view, with a jst template, I have to put a image that is in app/assets/images, on the css of the view or in the jst. but always get a 404 not found.

Comment: You need to get Rails to execute the `<%= asset_path ('logo.png') %>` part somewhere, then store the result in your Backbone model (or somewhere else that is accessible to your Backbone code), then access the path just like any other variable in your template.